# Visual Studio compiling with wrong version

Tags: c++, visual-studio, google-nativeclient

I have VS 2012 and VS 2013 installed on the same computer, and must use 2012 to compile Google NaCl with the vs-addin (Only supports 2012).

How can I change the compiler version that my Visual Studio software uses to compile code? I have clearly set the Platform Toolset to VS2012 (v11.0), but when compiling, I see the following error messages about version:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: hello_nacl_cpp, Configuration: Debug PPAPI ------
1>ppapi_cpp.lib(instance.o) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1800' doesn't match value '1700' in hello_nacl_cpp.obj
1>ppapi_cpp.lib(module.o) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1800' doesn't match value '1700' in hello_nacl_cpp.obj
1>ppapi_cpp.lib(var.o) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1800' doesn't match value '1700' in hello_nacl_cpp.obj
1>ppapi_cpp.lib(view.o) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1800' doesn't match value '1700' in hello_nacl_cpp.obj
1>ppapi_cpp.lib(ppp_entrypoints.o) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1800' doesn't match value '1700' in hello_nacl_cpp.obj
1>ppapi_cpp.lib(resource.o) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1800' doesn't match value '1700' in hello_nacl_cpp.obj
1>ppapi_cpp.lib(input_event.o) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1800' doesn't match value '1700' in hello_nacl_cpp.obj
1>ppapi_cpp.lib(url_loader.o) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1800' doesn't match value '1700' in hello_nacl_cpp.obj
1>ppapi_cpp.lib(core.o) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1800' doesn't match value '1700' in hello_nacl_cpp.obj
1>ppapi_cpp.lib(url_response_info.o) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1800' doesn't match value '1700' in hello_nacl_cpp.obj
1>ppapi_cpp.lib(file_ref.o) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1800' doesn't match value '1700' in hello_nacl_cpp.obj
```

I understand 1800 means VS 2013, but I am using 2012 to compile, and set the Platform Toolset to 2012 as well. Why would it still think that _MSC_VER is 1800, and how can I force it to use the one I've specified?

Comment: Do you have the project open in VS2013 or VS2012?

Comment: Everything should be 2012: Opened project in 2012, selected 2012 in platform toolchain.

Comment: Hey did you ever figure this out? Currently having this issue as well.